# Extra x tick not drawn in red (pgfplots)

Tags: pgfplots

The ticks of extra x tick are not drawn in red what I want to do.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
/pgf/declare function={f(\x)=0.8*\x + 4;}
]
\begin{axis}[
 restrict x to domain=0:30, xmax=30, xmin=0,
 restrict y to domain=0:26, ymax=26, ymin=0,
 x=0.25cm,
 y=0.25cm,
 axis x line = bottom,
 axis y line = left,
 xtick align=outside,
 ytick align=outside,
 tickwidth=0.1cm,
 axis line style = thick,
 major tick style=black,
 xtick={0,2,...,28},
 ytick={0,2,...,24},
 extra x ticks={7,9.6,11.68,13.344},
 extra x tick label={\null},
 extra y tick label={\null},
 extra x tick style={tick align=inside,tick style=red},
 y tick label style={
       /pgf/number format/1000 sep={}
   },
xlabel={$x$ (en milliers)},ylabel={$y$ (en milliers)},
every axis x label/.style={
at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},
anchor=west,
},
every axis y label/.style={
at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},
anchor=south,
},
samples=2000,
>=stealth,   
]
 \addplot [smooth,domain=0:30,thick] {f(x)} ;
 \addplot [smooth,domain=0:30,dashed,thick,red] {x} ;

  \draw[red,thick](7,{f(7)})--(9.6,{f(7)})--(9.6,{f(9.6)})--(11.68,{f(9.6)})--(11.68,{f(11.68)})--(13.344,{f(11.68)})--(13.344,{f(13.344)})--(14.6752,{f(13.344)});

\node[above,red] at (7,0){$a_0$};
\node[above,red] at (9.6,0){$a_1$};
\node[above,red] at (11.68,0){$a_2$};
\node[above,red] at (13.344,0){$a_3$};  

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems it's overridden by the `major tick style`. But use `major tick style` instead of `tick style` in the `extra x tick style`, and it works fine. Note I also used `ticklabel` for the extra ticks to add the `a_N` labels, and removed the nodes.

The commented `\addplot` is just to give you a tip about `const plot`. It doesn't produce exactly the same as your `\draw` though. Oh, and 2000 samples is a lot more than you actually need, it only leads to longer compilation time.

[image: close up of extra ticks]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
/pgf/declare function={f(\x)=0.8*\x + 4;}
]
\begin{axis}[
 restrict x to domain=0:30, xmax=30, xmin=0,
 restrict y to domain=0:26, ymax=26, ymin=0,
 x=0.25cm,
 y=0.25cm,
 axis x line = bottom,
 axis y line = left,
 xtick align=outside,
 ytick align=outside,
 tickwidth=0.1cm,
 axis line style = thick,
 major tick style=black,
 xtick={0,2,...,28},
 ytick={0,2,...,24},
 extra x ticks={7,9.6,11.68,13.344},
 extra x tick style={
   xticklabel={$a_{\ticknum}$},
   xticklabel style={above,red},
   tick align=inside,
   major tick style={red}
},
y tick label style={
       /pgf/number format/1000 sep={}
   },
xlabel={$x$ (en milliers)},ylabel={$y$ (en milliers)},
every axis x label/.style={
  at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},
  anchor=west,
},
every axis y label/.style={
  at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)},
  anchor=south,
},
samples=20,
>=stealth,   
]
 \addplot [domain=0:30,thick] {f(x)} ;
 \addplot [domain=0:30,dashed,thick,red] {x} ;

% \addplot [blue,const plot,samples at={7,9.6,11.68,13.344}] {f(x)};

  \draw[red,thick](7,{f(7)})--(9.6,{f(7)})--(9.6,{f(9.6)})--(11.68,{f(9.6)})--(11.68,{f(11.68)})--(13.344,{f(11.68)})--(13.344,{f(13.344)})--(14.6752,{f(13.344)});


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested `\addplot [blue,const plot,samples at={7,9.6,11.68,13.344}] {f(x)};`and I feel like I get the same result.

Comment: @Fabrice If you remove your `\draw`, you'll see that the last horizontal line isn't drawn. Add `14.6752` to the `samples at`, and you get that line, but an additional vertical line.